# Swift 5: iOS 15 FileManager – How to obtain the URL to the "Shortcuts" directory/folder in iCloud?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

I am writing an iOS 15 app (no need to worry about anything prior to iOS 15) that operate will between other processes in a workflow.

I need to be able to list/find files whose names will start with a known pattern.  These files will reside in one of two places:  1) The User's **`Downloads`** folder and 2) A folder titled **`XYZFolder`** under the **`Shortcuts`** folder.

The **`XYZFolder`** folder already exists as it was created by an iOS Shortcut.  That same Shortcut also created the files in that folder which my application needs to locate at a later date/time.

I am assuming that I can obtain a URL fairly easily to the **`Downloads`** folder since it *belongs* to the User.

---

### How do I go about obtaining a URL to the **`Shortcuts`** folder??

---

Comment: You can't just read files outside of your app's sandbox.  You will need to show a `UIDocumentPickerViewController` to let the user select files to which your app has access or you could have your app expose its documents folder to the files app and then the shortcut could put the folder/files in it directly

Comment: Isn't there someway that I (my app) can bookmark the folder once then have access to it forevermore?  I think I've seen apps do that.

Comment: Yes https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/providing_access_to_directories